# Install of opencv-python-headless takes a long time

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

When I install `opencv-python-headless` in Google Colab, it takes 15 minutes to complete.

My code:

```
! pip install --upgrade pip
! pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Here's a notebook with this code which recreates the problem:
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mherzog01/38b6cf71942a443da072f09bc097387f/slow-install-of-opencv-python-headless.ipynb.

The process eventually completes, but I'd like to reduce the time to install.

I saw from [`Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... -` runs forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669752/building-wheel-for-opencv-python-pep-517-runs-forever) a discussion about compiling OpenCV, which could very well be what is happening here.  However, this same SO post states that if you upgrade `pip`, it will use pre-built wheels.

**Edit:**  Added @intsco's workaround to the Google Colab

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Might be related to changes in OpenCV >=4.3 wheels https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#backward-compatibility

> Starting from 4.3.0 and 3.4.10 builds the Linux build environment was updated from manylinux1 to manylinux2014. This dropped support for old Linux distributions.

My workaround: `pip install "opencv-python-headless<4.3"`

Comment: This answer also provides a workaround to installing TensorFlow Object Detection -- just install ```opencv-python-headless<4.3``` before running their setup.  Works great!

Comment: `manylinux2014` is compatible with most GNU/Linux distributions released in 2014 or later. If your `pip` fails to install the `manylinux2014` wheels then it's most likely just too old. The issue isn't related to `manylinux2014`, it's related to missing wheels as described in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is the `--prefer-binary` flag: eg.

```
! pip install --prefer-binary opencv-python-headless
```

This is more flexible than speciying the version.

If you want it to fail in case no binary package is available, then you can use the `--only-binary` option for pip.
So you can do

```
! pip install --only-binary opencv-python-headless opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: This helps me to install latest version

Answer (score 3):

The install takes a long time since `pip` built the package from sources. The reason for that was that a new `opencv-python-headless` release was published to PyPI probably around the same time you tried to install it. It takes several hours for all the pre-built wheels to appear to PyPI. I believe the install works now fast, since all the wheels are in PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/4.4.0.46/#files

This problem can be avoided by pinning the version, e.g. `pip install opencv-python-headless==4.4.0.44`, and upgrading manually when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just install from apt before

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```