# Installation doesn't complete: process Clang takes up all CPU

Tags: python, opencv

When running `pip install opencv-contrib-python` it slows down the computer, CPU usage is 100%, full 16GB RAM is used. Something is wrong with my computer? I see 'Clang' taking up 98% of CPU.
Python version 3.8.9.

Comment: How long did you wait for the process to complete?

Comment: I have two laptops trying hard now. They are at 'Building wheel for opencv-contrib-python'. One laptop has achieved this and creates another wheel. This part takes a lot of time

Comment: Ah it seems normal to take 20 minutes, from these posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669752/building-wheel-for-opencv-python-pep-517-runs-forever

Comment: This solved it for me: pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel