# Building wheel for opencv-python keeps running for a very long time

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Building wheel for opencv-python keeps running for a very long time, while building the docker image. What can be done to make this run faster?

RUN pip install opencv-python

```
Collecting opencv-python
  Downloading opencv-python-4.6.0.66.tar.gz (90.3 MB)
```

...

```
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python, numpy
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...   
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml): still running...
```

Comment: how many minutes did you wait ?

Comment: seems like duplicate of  [\`Building wheel for opencv-python (PEP 517) ... -\` runs forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63669752/building-wheel-for-opencv-python-pep-517-runs-forever)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk its like 30-45 minutes and we also upgraded pip within Dockerfile

Comment: OpenCV is big. have some patience. and do not run this on a resource-constrained device like a raspberry, or if you do, expect it to take a while. -- why do you need to build at all? official opencv-python packages are binary and come for many architectures.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz this is on a t2.large machine and its still slow

Comment: what is a "t2.large"? it's nothing related to OpenCV or Python, as far as I can tell. anyway, does the link provided by Yunus help?

Comment: No it doesn't, t2.large is an AWS EC2 8GB instance

Answer (score 15):

I have also encountered the same issue in a low-level machine. Actually it takes long time but there is nothing wrong in backend. Run the installation command with `--verbose` so you can see what is happening actually behind.

When I have run the code:

```
sudo pip install opencv-python --verbose
```

I am able to track the process and also check the percentage of installation. So after 30 minutes it was still 30% completed - :)  a really low machine however we sometimes need to install it - After little patience, 2 hours later it is done, so whoever meeting this error this may help them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - In verbose mode it stuck on tests and .c installations.

I changed my py version from 3.6 to 3.8 and the installation finished in seconds!

Answer (score 0):

am also faced the same long running execution when am trying to install pyspark in my local machine. I have used `--verbose` to encounter the scene behind that and found the number of packages are copying the process of installation.

```
pip install opencv-python --verbose
```